# drag and drop database table to form doesn't respond

Tags: windows-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

I'm developing a Windows CE Mobile Application and using SQL Server Compact Edition as database server. However, I cannot drag and drop database tables from Server Explorer to a form's **design** view. It simply doesn't respond the drop. What could I be missing? I reinstalled and repaired everything. One note that I was able to do this operation a while ago. I also tried creating another database file and dropping tables of the famous **Northwind.sdf**.

Another thing is: I cannot generate a new data source within my project. When I try that the following error appears:

> An error occurred while creating the new data source:
>   An error occured while generating the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem couldn't be solved any of the suggested operations, but the following one.

Start the Visual Studio from the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

And everything works just fine.